# perl how to finish the script by 'cd $newdir'

Tags: bash, perl

I have a perl script that creates a directory `$newdir` based on some input passed as a parameter, and I would like the script to finish it's execution by doing:

```
cd $newdir
```

So that the next command in bash Linux 64bit (here `program2`) is executed from the `$newdir` working directory.

E.g.:

```
perl $HOME/import_script.pl -i someparameter && $HOME/program2 .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Any `cd` (or similar) you run in the perl script will affect only the perl script (or a sub-shell spawned from the perl script).

It can't affect the parent shell directly.

The only thing you could do would be to output the directory and then `cd` to that or similar. (e.g. `cd "$(perl "$HOME"/import_script.pl -i someparameter)" && "$HOME/program2" .` but realize that this means you can't output **anything** else to standard output from the perl script or it will confuse `cd`.)

Or have perl run the second command also, etc.

Comment: Gotcha. How can I pipe the output of the perl command to be the parameter for a `cd output` then?

Comment: @719016 what shell/OS?

Comment: Depending on the shell, you can't do that either. `cd` only takes an argument; it doesn't read from standard input. Some shells might allow a hack like `echo my_directory | cd <(cat)`, but most shells (`ksh` being an exception) run each side of the pipeline in a separate process, leading you to the same problem that prevents you from running `cd` inside your perl script. (And *some* shells provide an option to run the *last* process of a pipeline in the current shell, but we're getting into a *lot* of special circumstances required to do what you want.)

Comment: @chepner What shell does `echo my_directory | cd <(cat)`, would it not try `cd`ing to the temporary fd like /dev/fd/943 or whatever ?

Comment: Yes; I should have said `... | cd $(cat)`, which may or may not "work", depending on whether `cat` or `cd` gets first crack at standard input.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding another potential solution here; you can have your perl script output the bash you want to run, and run it with bash eval. For example;

**File: do.pl:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Temp qw(tempdir);

my $dir = tempdir();

print "echo Whatever I print out will be evaluated in my shell;";
print "cd $dir";   # Separate multiple commands with ';', see ^
```

**From Bash**

```
[~] > eval `./do.pl`
[~] > Whatever I print out will be evaluated in my shell
[/tmp/BcZI6ZaRB] > _
```

You can make things even easier by adding an alias, or bash function to your shell.

**Add to File: ~/.bashrc**

```
doit() {
    eval $(./do.pl)
}
```

**From Bash**

```
[~] > doit
[~] > Whatever I print out will be evaluated in my shell
[/tmp/ejzVGauPXx] > _
```